# sObject variable typeof Input and output in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I want to create an **sObject** variable in the **flow** and type is **Input and Output**.

I could not find anything related to my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to flow on which you want to create sObject variable. You can see a utility panel on left side. Click on **Resources** tab. You can see **SObject Variable** in list. Double click on that. A popup will open as in the image. Choose Input/Output type and Object type. Refer more on [flow variables](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_resources_variable.htm&type=0).

[image]